# MongoDB compass stuck on loading screen

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb compass is stuck at loading connection. I am attaching the screenshot for reference. I created the cluster and have entered for access from any IP. And I tried to connect with the link after the setup but it is stuck on loading forever. Please help. Thank you.[image]